Momentum density of electromagnetic field
I'm reading a textbook deriving the expression for the momentum densisty of the EM field and it starts with the following concept. Let's define the vector field $\vec{p}_\text{me}(\vec{r},t)$ to be the density of mechanical momentum of the charges. Then it is said that by Newton's second law we have:
$$\frac{\partial \vec{p}_\text{me}}{\partial t}=\rho\vec{E}+\vec{j}\times \vec{B}$$
However after integrating over a random volume $V$ I get a little confused:
$$\frac{d\vec{P}_\text{me}}{dt}=\int_V(\rho\vec{E}+\vec{j}\times \vec{B})d^3r $$
This is the rate of change of the total momentum enclosed in $V$ - $\vec{P}_\text{me}$. However since the particles are flowing in and out of $V$ shouldn't there be a convective term telling us how the momentum changes due to charges leaving and entering the volume? Also in the first equation shouldn't we have a full derivative? The partial one accounts for the change of the momentum field but not the flow of particles. Isn't it correct to say:
$$\frac{d\vec{p}_\text{me}}{dt}=\frac{\partial \vec{p}_\text{me}}{\partial t}+(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{p}_\text{me}=\rho\vec{E}+\vec{j}\times \vec{B}$$
But then the whole second formula would lose meaning.

You can derive the correct momentum conservation equation by using the Boltzmann equation. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation)
